# Find the Moment Generating Function of $X'AX$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

(1) $X_i \sim iid$ $N(0,1)$ and $A$ is symmetric. Find the MGF of $X'AX$.
(2) What if $A$ is idempotent and rank $m \le n$? Find MGF.

First, we should make $X'AX \sim N(0,I)$.
Since $A$ is symmetric, it can be decomposed as $C'DC$ where $C$ is orthogonal.
$CX \sim N(0,I)$
I stuck here...
Any suggestion or kind explanation will be thankful.

Comment: Multivariate Normal Distribution.

Comment: @Samprity Yes, I know I have to use that. But is there any special process related to "symmetric" part?

Comment: Yes for the word "symmetric", i.e. $A$ is a symmetric martix you can say $\cov(X_i, X_j) = \cov(X_j, X_i)$.

Comment: @Samprity I have a problem. To show MGF, I want to make $Y=X'AX \sim N(0,I)$, how to make it?

Comment: Let me give an hint for your first problem. When $A$ is a positive definite or non-singular symmetric matrix you shall get non-singular matrix $C$ such that $C^T A^{-1} C = I$. Now use the transformation $X - \mu = CY$. $\mu = \bar{X} = E(X)$. Now $Y$ will follow $N(0,I)$.

Comment: @Samprity Sorry, I don't get what you mean. But I use the MGF of $\chi^2$ since if we define $Y=CX$ then $Y'DY \sim \chi^2(n)$.

Comment: It is not as you are saying. Let me be frank. These things are not very clear to me. See page 41 of "An Introduction to Multivariate Statistical Analysis" by "T. W. Anderson". The calculation is done for Characteristic Function completely. I hope you shall get sufficient hints for doing it for Moment Generating function. I suggested after seeing it.

Comment: @Samprity I don't have that book so I downloaded it from google and read the page 41. Still don't get any hint for this question. I can't understand why my solution is wrong. Why don't you post your own answer or explain more precisely about the part which you think I'm wrong. I would appreciate it.